# Perl Format: Not enough format arguments

Tags: perl, format

I am currently having trouble with formatting my output. I understand that this may be "bad practice", but using format is a requirement.

I am attempting to get a print out of the values that I retrieved from the database into a template of a SQL insert for Netcool.

I'm referencing http://perldoc.perl.org/perlform.html to apply the proper variables but I'm not sure why this is not working.

Here is a code snippet:

```
129 foreach my $row (@{$rows}) {
130
131   $trigger_name         = removeNull($row->{triggername});
132   $trigger_group        = $row->{groupname};
133   $trigger_kind         = $row->{triggerkind};
134   $code_block           = $row->{codeblock};
135   $isDebugEnabled       = IntToLiteralBoolean($row->{debugenabled});
136   $isEnabled            = IntToLiteralBoolean($row->{isenabled});
137   $priority             = $row->{triggerpriority};
138   $comment_block        = $row->{commentblock};
139   $evaluate_block       = $row->{evaluateblock};
140   $bind_name            = $row->{bindname};
141   $condition_block      = $row->{conditionblock};
142   $declare_block        = $row->{declareblock};
143
144 #  my $sth_triggerType;
145
146   if($trigger_kind == 0) {
147     #database logic goes here
148     my $sql_getDatabaseFields = "select *
149                                  from catalog.database_triggers
150                                  where TriggerName = '$trigger_name'";
151
152     print "\n\nExtracting trigger: $trigger_name";
153     print "\nTriggerKind: Database, $trigger_kind";
154
155     my $sth_triggerType = $dbh->prepare($sql_getDatabaseFields);
156     $sth_triggerType->execute;
157     my $dbRows = $sth_triggerType->fetchall_arrayref({});
158
159     foreach my $row (@{$dbRows}) {
160       $event_order       = $row->{eventorder};
161       $event_op          = $row->{eventop};
162       $database_name     = $row->{databasename};
163       $table_name        = $row->{tablename};
164       $event_level       = $row->{eventlevel};
165       write;
166
167      # print "\nEvent Order: $event_order";
168      # print "\nEvent Op: $event_op";
169      # print "\nDatabase Name:$database_name";
170      # print "\nTable name:$table_name";
171      # print "\nEvent Level: $event_level";
172     }
173 format =
174
175 CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER @<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
176                           $trigger_name
177 GROUP @<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
178       $trigger_group
179 DEBUG @<<<<<<<<<<<<
180       $isDebugEnabled
181 ENABLED @<<<<<<<<<<<<
182       $isEnabled
183 PRIORITY @<<
184       $priority
185 COMMENT ^<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
186   $comment_block
187   ~~^<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
188   $comment_block
189   ^<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
190   $comment_block
191   ^<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
192   $comment_block
193   ^<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
194   $comment_block
195   ^<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
196
197 begin
198   ^<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
199   $code_block
200   ~~^<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
201   $code_block
202   ^<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
203   $code_block
204   ^<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
205   $code_block
206   ^<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
207   $code_block
208   ^<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
209   $code_block
210   ^<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
211   $code_block
212   ^<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
213   $code_block
214   ^<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
215   $code_block
216   ^<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
217   $code_block
218   ^<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
219   $code_block
220   ^<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
221   $code_block
222   ^<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
223   $code_block
224   ^<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
225   $code_block
226 end;
227 .
```

This is the output when debugging:

```
Extracting trigger: service_reinsert
Not enough format arguments at nc_trigger_extract.pl line 199.
 at nc_trigger_extract.pl line 199
        main::STDOUT called at nc_trigger_extract.pl line 165
Modification of a read-only value attempted at nc_trigger_extract.pl line 199.
 at nc_trigger_extract.pl line 199
        main::STDOUT called at nc_trigger_extract.pl line 165
Debugged program terminated.  Use q to quit or R to restart,

139:      $evaluate_block       = $row->{evaluateblock};
140:      $bind_name            = $row->{bindname};
141:      $condition_block      = $row->{conditionblock};
142==>b   $declare_block        = $row->{declareblock};
143
144     #  my $sth_triggerType;
145
146:      if($trigger_kind == 0) {
147         #database logic goes here
148:        my $sql_getDatabaseFields = "select *


    DB<2> x $code_block
    0  "\cJ\cIset old.LastReportAt = new.LastReportAt;\cJ\cJ\cIif ( old.CurrentState != new.CurrentState )\cJ\cIthen\cJ\cI\cIset old.CurrentState = new.CurrentState;\cJ\cI\cIset old.StateChange = new.StateChange;\cJ\cIend if;\cJ\cJ\cIif ( new.CurrentState = 0 )\cJ\cIthen\cJ\cI\cIset old.LastGoodAt = new.LastGoodAt;\cJ\cIelseif ( new.CurrentState = 1 )\cJ\cIthen\cJ\cI\cIset old.LastMarginalAt = new.LastMarginalAt;\cJ\cIelseif ( new.CurrentState = 2 )\cJ\cIthen\cJ\cI\cIset old.LastBadAt = new.LastBadAt;\cJ\cIend if;\cJ\c@"

 DB<4> x $comment_block
0  "Service processing for service.status\c@"
  DB<5> c
```

Comment: Just a guess: but probably your `$code_block` variable is somehow read-only. If you use the multiline `^`, the original variable will be altered (the beginning will be chopped). Also, it seems to me like you have some redundant lines in your format, as you `~~` marker in the second line of your "code_block" and "comment_block" fields. Maybe try something like `$code_block = "".$row->{codeblock};`. It's far too long ago I used `format` to give proper advice, but here are some directions you could try until the `format` experts are drippling in (if there still are some).

Comment: Why would you post 100 lines of code? If you can't post an example that's 10 -15 lines long and demonstrates your problem, then you haven't spent enough time working on your code.   And, what does database code have to do with a format problem?  Why did you post the database code?

Comment: @7stud I'm new to the perl format so I wasn't sure if it was the data being passed that was the issue. The encoding is different and I was not sure as to how it affects this code. I wanted to be clear and provide as much information as possible to help. I apologize for trying to be more detailed, Stud times 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare the following two examples:

1)

```
my $code_block = "helloworld";
my $str = "mars";

format = 
  ^<<<<
  $str
begin
  ^<<<<
  $code_block
  ^<<<<
  $code_block
  ^<<<<
  $code_block
end;
.

write STDOUT;

--output:--
  mars
begin
  hello
  world

end;
```

2)

```
my $code_block = "helloworld";
my $str = "mars";

format = 
  ^<<<<
begin           #LINE 11
  ^<<<<
  $code_block
  ^<<<<
  $code_block
  ^<<<<
  $code_block
end;
.

write STDOUT;

--output:--
Modification of a read-only value attempted at 1.pl line 11.
```